# At the moment with present perfect

Tags: grammar, conjugation

Yesterday I was doing some english exercises and I've had some problems with a sentence:

At the moment, most of the work is being done. (solution)

At the moment, most of the work has been done. (my answer)

Why wasn't mine right? The context says that a lot of work in the house has been done (the walls have been put on, the roof has been put on and the bathroom has been fit), so now it only remains to paint the walls and to fit the kitchen.

Comment: The 'official' version seems to need something more. "...most of the work is being done by Bob the builder", or "...most of the work is being done at weekends."  Your version works if you continue "...there is just the kitchen to be fitted and the walls to paint."

Comment: _At the moment, some work remains to be done_ is unambiguous. The difficulty lies in the meaning of 'most' which requires definition.. 'Some' is less precise.

Comment: 'At the moment, most of the work has been done' is an awkward pairing. 'Now, most of the work has been done' causes no such problems, but 'at the moment' doesn't work with a perfect aspect situation. If 'the work' is a variable, more coming in over time, you can probably get away with say 'At the moment, most of the work has been done, but we're expecting a lot more to come in in the near future.' But this is not the case with the situation given in the question, with a notionally fixed total amount of 'work'.

Answer (score 1):

The time adverbial' at the moment' indicates that the action is in progress at time of speaking.

However, if you want to emphasize the finished work, you can simply say:

most of the work has been finished.